# Getting deep typescript type in a less verbose way

Tags: typescript, types, supabase, supabase-database

I would like to abstract deep path to a type.

Right onto **example data type:** *(type generated by Supabase)*

```js
export interface Database {
    public: {
        Tables: {
            profiles: {
                Row: {
                    email: string;
                    full_name: string | null;
                    id: string;
                    is_complete: boolean;
                };
                Insert: {...};
                Update: {...};
            },
            project: {...},
            service: {...},
            ...
        },
        Views: {...},
        ...
    };
};
```

What is uinder `Row` is my data structure I'm trying to assign to a varialbe. The way to go right now is

```js
const profiles: Database['public']['Tables']['profiles']['Row']
```

Is there a way to abstract it somehow?

**Ideal abstraction would be:**

```js
const profiles: Profiles // Pointing to Database['public']['Tables']['profiles']['Row']

const profiles: SomeTypeSelectFunction['profiles'] // Could also do
```

In general could only find some info about generics and constraining them, but can't yet seem to find a way to achieve this what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ChatGPT is one hell of a fellow. Just copy pasted this question and got a working answer with an concise and easy to understand explanation of why it works

This is what I've got:

```js
type TableSelector<T extends keyof Database['public']['Tables']> = Database['public']['Tables'][T]['Row'];

const profiles: TableSelector<'profiles'>;
```

> The `TableSelector` type takes a table name as a type argument (in
> this case, the `'profiles'` table), and returns the row type for that
> table. With this type selector function, you can easily select the row
> type for any table in the `Database` type by passing the table name as
> a type argument.

---

I've validated that answer is working, and hope people will use upvote responsibly as described in [Stack Overflow GPT Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) to further strengthen the accuracy of knowledge base of the community.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Comment: You should probably delete this answer before someone else does it for you, especially in light of the fact that "moderators are empowered (at their discretion) to issue immediate suspensions of up to 30 days to users who are copying and pasting GPT content onto the site, with or without prior notice or warning."

Comment: Thank you for the information, wasn't aware prior to posting. Tho after reading the policy I do not think it actually violates it. I'm keeping the question and answer as I see value in having them here for others to read. I've added little note to the answer just to double validate the accuracy of it. If moderators still thinks it should not be here, I'd be surprised. But feel free to remove it if I misunderstood something (hopefully without suspension hahah). Cheers ✌️